# Plotting, columns with multiple word name

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I am able to read a file 'data.csv' that looks something like this:

```
Time, Upper Layer Temperature,...,
0, 450,...,
...
```

Using pandas:

```
data=pd.read_table('data.csv',header=0,sep=',')
```

To plot, I can't seem to get syntax right:

```
pl.plot(data.Time,data.'Upper Layer Temperature',label="ULT")
```

What is the correct way to be able to plot by column name when the column name has multiple words separated by spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary-style access instead of attribute-style, namely `data["Upper Layer Temperature"]`. For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B has a space": [10,20,30]})
>>> df
   A  B has a space
0  1             10
1  2             20
2  3             30

[3 rows x 2 columns]
>>> df["B has a space"]
0    10
1    20
2    30
Name: B has a space, dtype: int64
>>> plt.plot(df["A"], df["B has a space"], label="fred")
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xb75106c>]
```

---

But note, the way you're reading in your file, you're probably going to have an extra space in the column names:

```
>>> !cat data.csv
Time, Upper Layer Temperature,...,
0, 450,...,
>>> data=pd.read_table('data.csv',header=0,sep=',')
>>> data.columns
Index([u'Time', u' Upper Layer Temperature', u'...', u'Unnamed: 3'], dtype='object')
```

You might be able to use `skipinitialspace=True` to avoid this:

```
>>> data=pd.read_table('data.csv',header=0,sep=',',skipinitialspace=True)
>>> data.columns
Index([u'Time', u'Upper Layer Temperature', u'...', u'Unnamed: 3'], dtype='object')
```